# How to List Thumbnails based on Custom Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, post-thumbnails

I need to list(display) all thumbnails from my Custom Post Types in a page template based on product categories. For Example I have a Custom Category called "Art" and some images(Custom Post Type) products enabled by "Feature Image" associated with "Art" Category.Now I would like to list ONLY all thumbnails of Art category product on my Custom Page Template.

Can you please let me know how to do this? I find this method which works only for one page without ability to select from pages!

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use custom post and make the categorys there and align the thumbnails in each post.

```
 <?php // query post type */*/

        global $post;
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'YOUR-POST-TYPE-HERE',
        'cat' => $category,
        'suppress_filters' => '0',
        'numberposts' =>'-1',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'post_status' => 'publish' );   
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );

        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
        $meta = $custom_metabox_jurister->the_meta();?>
```

**And check if post have thumnail:**

```
<?php // Checks if there is a thumbnail and displays it
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 

                $size = 'thumbnail';
                $attr = array(
                'class' => 'post-logo');
                echo '<div class="image">';
                echo the_post_thumbnail('large', $attr);
                echo '</div>';
                } 
                else{ 
                // Do nothing
                } 
    ?>
```

Change the code , to fit your idea.

**Not sure if I understood exactly what you wanted to do. But hope this helps.**

Comment: Hi Meias and thanks for your comment. Do I have to add both parts to Page Template?

Comment: Both parts in the same order and template. And change it to fit your code.

Comment: well, I am getting this error message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/84/10393684/html/wp-content/themes/myPress/page Gallery.php on line 23

Comment: try removing, $meta = $custom_metabox_jurister->the_meta(); part.

Comment: same! I am getting same issue!

Comment: Please edit the question with more code